# Entity Framework Memory Management and Dispose?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using EF (EF Core, actually, with ASP.NET Core on OSX, but I believe this is more of a general "newbie-style" EF question, so please read on...)

I built a little logging routine that uses EF to publish log entries to my database. Sort of like this, called from a repository class:

```
WebLog log = new WebLog(source, path, message);
Context.WebLogs.Add(log);
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Where `WebLog` is a simple model class, `Context.WebLogs` is a `DbSet<WebLog>` collection, and `Context` is obviously the `DbContext`. I believe this is quite straightforward.

But my question is this: if I continue to add new log entries to the `Context.WebLogs` collection and I never do anything like reboot my server, isn't the collection just going to grow without bounds? Is there some kind of "purge" or "flush" action I can take periodically to manage memory usage (without affecting the committed rows in the database, of course--I want those to persist). Or is `DbSet` some sort of a special collection that won't do this?

Comment: the action you are looking for is just detaching all entities that are in an Unchanged State. I highly doubt EF would do something like that on its own, which is one of the reasons the context (entry) lifetime should be limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by DevilSuichiro above, the recommended approach is to limit the lifetime of the instances of `DbContext`. E.g. in a Web application you typically use a `DbContext` instance per request, so an unbounded number of entities added doesn't become a problem.

The closest thing to a "flush" operation is `SaveChanges()` that method will not try to remove references to tracked entities, as  DbContext  is designed to be reused after `SaveChanges()`.

In previous versions of EF we had a `Detach()` API that you could use to get rid of an individual tracked reference but we don't have that API in `DbContext` or anywhere in EF Core.

BTW, having an instance of `DbContext` that is shared between multiple requests is extremely problematic because `DbContext` is not thread safe.